# Looking for an IFRAME like ASP.NET Server Control

Tags: asp.net, iframe

Does anybody knows, if there is an (free) **IFRAME like ASP.NET server control** ? It shoud behave like a container control, which adjust itself the width and height dependend on the browser resolution respectively the width/height of its parent control.
Background: I want to show/run a web-application inside a web-application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should have a look at UFrame.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/uframe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the RadWindow by Telerik will suite you. You can open up 'Windows' on your page.
It has an extensive client API, so you can control the dimensions anyway you want.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/behaviors/defaultcs.aspx

I use it to open up an edit page(.aspx) that will load/save data and then close itself.

Comment: unfortunately it is an commercial control